# Part # 6 failed to upload. The request timed out

Tags: ios, react-native, testflight

I have a react-native project and trying to archive the build to upload on Testflight. It archives successfully but when it comes to upload it gives the following Errors. Can't find help on stackoverflow related to this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this happens when you are using multiple apple developer accounts in Xcode. I used Transporter App to upload my build. That worked once, but not always.